# QGIS 3.16.6 - Annotation Text

Tags: qgis, layers, annotation, link

QGIS 3.16.6

**What was done initially**
Created **8** annotation text boxes and toggled these off (Ctrl + t). Later, on a different day reopening the same project, **4** more (forgetting the previous were toggled off) were created. I began linking the 4 new annotations to layers they are associated with via:
 "Annotation Text" > "Linked Layer" > *linked to a visible layer*
Thus when making a layer invisible, the annotation boxes also became invisible and visible only when the layer was made visible again.

At some point in playing with toggling annotation boxes on and off for different layers during print composer map exporting, I saw the previous 8 boxes and linked these to associated layers and toggled these off. Now, however, **2** annotation texts from the newer are missing in action and when I toggle the annotation boxes the remaining newer ones and the previous 8 do not all go on at the same time (Ctrl + t = 2 on and 8 off; doing this again = 8 on and 2 off).

**Question**
Is there a way to see **ALL** created annotation texts linked to specific layers within the project? Through layer properties or elsewhere in project menus.
Is there a way to have all annotation text visible at the same time? SQL script of some sort.

**Tried**
Restarting project
Turning layers off and on and (Ctrl + t)
Not super great with code, but trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue Work Around/Resolution**

Why it was happening: Annotation is toggled 'off' and a new annotation box is created resulting these boxes to appear in opposite toggle positions.

Work Around: Decide which is your main toggle 'on' position and only add annotation boxes in that instance. I copy pasted from one to the other and deleted the annotation boxes in my designated toggle 'off' position.